# I couldn't figure out how to use max function in Python

Tags: python, list, function, max

Programming is new to me, it's my third day as a programmer and I am trying to solve Project Euler problems then I got stuck with problem number 4:

> Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

Here is my solution:

```
for a in range(100, 1000):
    for b in range(100, 1000):
        if str(a * b) == str(a * b) [ : :-1]:
            largest = max(a *b)
            print(largest)
```

I found all palindromes without the `largest = max(a * b)` line but I couldn't find the largest number and got confused about the usage of the `max` function. Could you please help and explain to me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`max` is used with a collection of numbers (2 or more), not just one, you can mimic it using your own variable:

```
largest = 0 # this will hold the maximum palindrome

for a in range(100, 1000):
    for b in range(a, 1000):
        c = a * b  #  calculate a * b one time only for each iteration
        if (str(c) == str(c)[::-1]) and c > largest:
            largest = c

print(largest)  #  ===>  906609
```

The second loop is starting at `a` to avoid repeatition of calculations (e.g.: `100 * 999` will be calculated but `999 * 100` won't be, because multiplication is commutative).

Using `max`, you can do it like this:

```
largest = max(a * b for a in range(100, 1000) for b in range(a, 1000) if str(a * b) == str(a * b)[::-1])

print(largest)  #  ===>  906609
```

And, in Python 3.8+, you can use the walrus operator to calculate `a * b` one time only for each iteration:

```
largest = max(c for a in range(100, 1000) for b in range(a, 1000) if str(c := a * b) == str(c)[::-1])

print(largest)  #  ===>  906609
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use `max` built-in function over an iterable:

from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max):

> max(arg1, arg2, *args[, key])
>
> Return the largest item in an iterable or the largest of two or more
>   arguments.

you can use:

```
max(a * b for a in range(100, 1000) for b in range(100, 1000) if str(a * b) == str(a * b) [ : :-1])
```

output:

```
906609
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a logic issue in your code.

You are looping through all the 'a', for all 'a' you are then looping on all the 'b'.
For all the 'b' of all the 'a' you are saying largest is the max of a single number 'a * b' (which doesn't make much sense) then you print that.

You have two solutions:

1. Either you initialize your 'largest' as 0 (as your result is positive) and then if you find a result, check if it is larger than the current one (initialized as 0), if it is, replace it. When do you do this ? When you don't need to keep other result, only the max is important.
2. You create an empty list and every time you have a result, you add it to this list then at the end you look for the max of this list. When you do this ? When you will use the other values later on, inconveniant is that you store everything and then do a max on it (less performant)

Answer (score 1):

`max()` is the wrong function to use here. The result of `max(any_number)` with `any_number` being a scalar value will always be the value of `any_number` itself.

What you need to do, is to keep track of the largest palindrom found so far. And if you find a palindrom larger than that, to overwrite the record taking variable:

```
# This variable keeps track of the largest palindrom found
largest = 0

for a in range(100, 1000):
    for b in range(100, 1000):

        res = a * b

        # Check if you found a palindrome
        if str(res) == str(res) [::-1]:

            # Check if the found palindrom is larger 
            # than the currently largest found palindrome
            if res > largest:
                largest = res
print(largest)
```

Answer (score 1):

Following from MrGeek's answer, you could use the max() function (which requires two arguments or a list) as such:

```py
largest = 0 # this will hold the maximum palindrome

for a in range(100, 1000):
    for b in range(a, 1000):
        c = a * b
        if (str(c) == str(c)[::-1]):
            largest = max(c, largest)

print(largest)
```

Here is the documentation for the function:

- https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max

Answer (score 1):

(max/min) functions are applied to an iterable to find (largest/smallest) value. Therefore you need to store values in a list and apply the function.

```
palindrome_lst = list()

for a in range(100, 1000):
    for b in range(100, 1000):
        if (str(a*b))==(str(a * b)[ : :-1]):
            pal = str(a*b)
            palindrome_lst.append(int(pal))

print(max(palindrome_lst))
```